# Problems using Hibernate and Spring in Wicket

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, wicket

I'm writing a little web-interface for a database I created. The database access is done through Hibernate, but it also uses Spring for injecting instances of DAO's (which in turn have a SessionFactory injected). I test the web-interface on an embedded Jetty server. Everything works fine when used independently: I can get stuff out of the database from the database project, I can run a webpage using Wicket on the Jetty server, I even managed to get Spring working for the WicketTester, which was a bit of a pain in the ass. But now when I try to get something out of the database (by clicking some button on the webpage), I get an error saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
     at nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.core.controller.DAO.GenericDAO.getCurrentSession(GenericDAO.java:37)
```

Somehow the sessionFactory that should have been injected in the DAO wasn't injected. I defined the DAO bean in applicationContext.xml of the Wicket module, but I assumed that as soon as it would see the @Autowired of the SessionFactory it would look in the spring.xml file of thát project, but apparently it doesn't. I'll put some code below to show the individual parts at work.

The WicketApplication:

```
@Service
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    @SpringBean
    private IPDBEntryDAO    pdbEntryDAO;

    public IPDBEntryDAO getPdbEntryDAO() {
        return pdbEntryDAO;
    }

    public void setPdbEntryDAO(IPDBEntryDAO pdbEntryDAO) {
        this.pdbEntryDAO = pdbEntryDAO;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<HomePage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#init()
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml").getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    public void setupInjector() {
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
    }
}
```

The class which starts the embedded Jetty server (copied from the Wicket quickstart):

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int timeout = (int) Duration.ONE_HOUR.getMilliseconds();

        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

        // Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
        connector.setMaxIdleTime(timeout);
        connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // check if a keystore for a SSL certificate is available, and
        // if so, start a SSL connector on port 8443. By default, the
        // quickstart comes with a Apache Wicket Quickstart Certificate
        // that expires about half way september 2021. Do not use this
        // certificate anywhere important as the passwords are available
        // in the source.

        Resource keystore = Resource.newClassPathResource("/keystore");
        if (keystore != null && keystore.exists()) {
            connector.setConfidentialPort(8443);

            SslContextFactory factory = new SslContextFactory();
            factory.setKeyStoreResource(keystore);
            factory.setKeyStorePassword("wicket");
            factory.setTrustStoreResource(keystore);
            factory.setKeyManagerPassword("wicket");
            SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(factory);
            sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(timeout);
            sslConnector.setPort(8443);
            sslConnector.setAcceptors(4);
            server.addConnector(sslConnector);

            System.out.println("SSL access to the quickstart has been enabled on port 8443");
            System.out.println("You can access the application using SSL on https://localhost:8443");
            System.out.println();
        }

        WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
        bb.setServer(server);
        bb.setContextPath("/");
        bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");

        // START JMX SERVER
        // MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        // MBeanContainer mBeanContainer = new MBeanContainer(mBeanServer);
        // server.getContainer().addEventListener(mBeanContainer);
        // mBeanContainer.start();

        server.setHandler(bb);

        try {
            System.out.println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP");
            server.start();
            System.in.read();
            System.out.println(">>> STOPPING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER");
            server.stop();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>web-interface</display-name>

    <!--
        There are three means to configure Wickets configuration mode and they 
        are tested in the order given.

        1) A system property: -Dwicket.configuration 
        2) servlet specific <init-param> 
        3) context specific <context-param>

        The value might be either "development" (reloading when templates change) or 
        "deployment". If no configuration is found, "development" is the default. -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.web-interface</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationBean</param-name>
            <param-value>wicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.web-interface</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- The SpringWebApplicationFactory will need access to a Spring Application context, configured like this... -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
</web-app>
```

The applicationContext.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!--
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter" />
    -->

    <!-- setup wicket application -->
    <bean id="wicketApplication" class="nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.WicketApplication">
        <property name="pdbEntryDAO" ref="pdbEntryDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pdbEntryDAO" class="nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.core.controller.DAO.PDBEntryDAO" />
</beans>
```

Part of the DAO class from the database module:

```
public class GenericDAO<I> implements IGenericDAO<I> {
    private Class<I>        persistentClass;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory  sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDAO() {
        persistentClass = (Class<I>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }


    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

The spring.xml file used by the database module:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter" />

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.core.model.domain" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Sorry for posting so much code, but I think I might let important stuff out if I don't.

Does anyone know how to make sure everything gets injected, both for the Wicket module as for the database module?

Comment: Do you really *need* the database connection? In every usecase I came across it was much easier and much more maintainable to inject mocked DAOs for testing.

Comment: True, but I'm still curious why the sessionFactory in the external piece of code doesn't get injected. I know the applicationContext.xml in the Wicket module doesn't include any information about this, but the spring.xml in the database module does, so how can I get Spring to use that one as well, and automagically if that's possible, or is something else going wrong here which causes it to not be injected?

Comment: Btw, it doesn't seem to be a problem of the tester, as you mention, I can just use mockup DAO's there, but when I just run the Embedded Jetty server and look at the page (localhost:8080) I get that same error.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to divert attention from the Wicket testing a bit, because that isn't really the problem here, it's the injection of the sessionFactory withing the DAO that doesn't seem to work when I access it from the Wicket module, but does work from all other modules.

Comment: I think you must import the context of your databse module (spring.xml) into your wicket module'S context (application.xml). That is what I do (I also use wicket, spring and hibernate) and it works like a charm. The only difference is that I use java annotations to set up all this.

Comment: I tried, and even thought when I run the test it seems to be doing a lot of hibernate related stuff in the console, it doesn't when I just run the server and check localhost:8080, it still gives the error that the session returned from getCurrentSession() equals null. I included an OpenSessionInView filter in the web.xml but this doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: you can try adding "Injector.get().inject(this);" in the constructor of your page. Also do you use the wicket-spring integration from wicket?

Comment: I'll try that when I'm back at work. And yes, I use the wicket-spring package

Comment: Have you look into `wicket-spring`'s `@SpringBean`
[More info on Wicket Spring](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring.html)